# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors computation

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $T$ be the $n \times n$ matrix with every entry equal to $1$. I computed the E-values and E-vectors as follows and was wondering if it is correct:

Since every component of $Tv$ equals $v_1 + ... +v_n$ it is evident that $n$ is an eigenvalue and $(1)=(1,1,1,1....)$ is a corresponding eigenvector.

Next I observed that every column is a multiple of the first. Hence the null space of $T$ has dimension $n-1$. As far as I understand the null space is the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ (if it is non-trivial). Therefore to find eigenvectors corresponding to $0$ it is enough to find $n-1$ linearly independent vectors. It is evident that the vectors $v_i$ of the form $1$ at the first component and $-1$ at $i$ for $i>1$ satisfy this requirement.

Thank you for checking my solution.

Comment: What od you mean by $(1)$ as vector? Surely you are not assuming $n=1$?

Comment: @newb The bulked up appearance of text you wrote is extremely demotivating to read. I suggest adding some line breaks. I don't know about other people, but guessing by the lack of answers to a question as simple as this, I suppose they feel the same as me.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I meant $(1)$ as the vector with all entries equal to $1$. No I didn't mean to assume $n=1$.

Comment: Hrm, I didn't have any trouble at all, and though there is one large paragraph I thought it was very direct. It *is* good advice though, @newb to be sensitive about using linebreaks to make text readable.

Comment: @rschwieb Aight. Maybe it's just me. I don't even start reading such texts, to be honest.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a good idea to short-write two different things by the same letters: EV...

Comment: @GitGud I have seen plenty of examples of exactly what you described, so I think your advice is very good. I hope you don't stop giving it :) Example: http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/452023/1

Comment: @rschwieb $\ddot \smile$ I would insta-ignore that.

Comment: @DonAntonio I tried to correct it.

Comment: Hey @GitGud, what's the hyper-sensitivity? If you open a random newspaper or novel you'll find plenty of paragraphs with ten or more lines. Are you suggesting you wouldn't even consider reading them? (I even write comments to MSE questions that come close to that, within the limit of the allowed number of keystrokes, but I have the excuse that it is impossible break comments into separate paragraphs.)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Novels are different type of text and even those have linebreaks. Paragraphs are just as good as linebreaks. So it makes for a more pleaseant reading (at least to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that is a fine way to do it. You correctly noticed that $T(1,\dots,1)=n(1,\dots,1)$ would yield one eigenvalue $n$, and then secondly noted that the rank of the matrix is obviously $1$, so that the rest of the eigenvalues are $0$. The candidate eigenvectors for eigenvalue $0$ are also straightforwardly chosen. Very efficient :)

Comment: Thank you! And thank you for taking the time to check my solution!

Comment: @newb Being able to avoid computation with inspection is a valuable skill, where it can be applied efficiently. So many students would immediately plunge into a matrix computation...